# Selenium Web Driver Java Parallel Execution in IEDriverServer(x32).exe random Failures

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, internet-explorer, testng

When executing test in Parallel (4 threads) in IE11 using TestNG, the executions tends to fail at random position with no exact issue. The scripts were able to execute in Chrome/Safari(Mac)/Firefox with 100% pass rates, but when comes to IE 11 the Pass rate drops to 20% or less. (Total Count Around 180 Test Cases)

**The parallel execution Implementation structure**

1. Created a Thread Local Class and Set the current execution driver to a new Thread.
   `ThreadLocal<TestCase> localThread = new ThreadLocal<TestCase>();`
2. Test Case Class

   ```
      public class TestCase{
             private WebDriver driver = null;
             private string browser;
             private starttime;
      }
   ```
3. For each command(Click. Type) the driver is taken from the current thread and execute.
   `WebDriver driver = ThreadLocalClass.getTestCase().getDriver();`
4. Execution done via Test NG test planner

   ```
       <suite name="TestSuite" verbose="3" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">
             <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
           <class name="com.bulk.TS_UserCreation">
             <methods>
                <include name="tc_CreateAdminUser" />
                <include name="tc_CreateGuestUser" />
             </methods>
          </class>
       </classes>
       </test>
     </suite>
   ```

Comment: Does this article helps? http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/random-selenium-webdriver-tests-inconsistently-fail-and-pass-on-ie-browser